# Detect if user's locale is set to 12-hour or 24-hour timeformat using javascript

Tags: javascript, browser, datetime-format, time-format

how to check whether the user is using 12hr or 24hr time format using Javascript with or without using 3rd party library like moment.js 
I also tried `new Date().toLocaleString()` but it is not working tested in firefox and google chrome. firefox always shows 12hr format and chrome always shows 24hrs time format

Answer (score 7):

@Marko Bonaci's answer was helpful. I researched his comment "I'm not sure whether AM/PM designation (whichever characters are used) is at the end of the output for all locales." A Google search listed [this link](https://spanishdict.com/answers/174077/when-keeping-time-how-do-you-translate-am-morning-and-pm-evening) stating a user's comment:

> The Latin abbreviations a.m. and p.m.
> (often written "am" and "pm", "AM" and "PM", or "A.M." and "P.M.")
> are used in English, Portuguese (Brazilian) and Spanish.
> The equivalents in Greek are π.µ. and µ.µ. respectively.

This can be verified from the browser's console using the two letter [ISO 639-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes) code "el" or the three letter ISO 639-2 code "ell":

```
new Intl.DateTimeFormat(["el"], { hour: "numeric" }).format();
// or
new Intl.DateTimeFormat("ell", { hour: "numeric" }).format();
```

These lines will return a value with the localized "AM"/"PM" string:

```
'7 π.μ.'
'7 μ.μ.'
```

I ended up using his suggestion using the built-in '[Number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number)' object in JavaScript.

```
// UK english
Number.isInteger(Number(new Intl.DateTimeFormat("en-UK", { hour: "numeric" }).format()));
// Returns 'true'

// Greek
Number.isInteger(Number(new Intl.DateTimeFormat("el", { hour: "numeric" }).format()));
// Returns 'false'

// U.S.
Number.isInteger(Number(new Intl.DateTimeFormat("en-US", { hour: "numeric" }).format()));
// Returns 'false'
```

Here's my function with comments:

```
const isBrowserLocaleClockType24h = (languages) => {
    // "In basic use without specifying a locale, DateTimeFormat
    // uses the default locale and default options."
    // Ref: developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat#using_datetimeformat
    // To be sure of the browser's language (set by the user
    // and may be different than the operating system's default language)
    // set the 'languages' parameter to 'navigator.language'.
    // E.g. isBrowserLocaleClockType24h(navigator.language);
    if (!languages) { languages = []; }

    // The value of 'hr' will be in the format '0', '1', ... up to '24'
    // for a 24-hour clock type (depending on a clock type of
    // 'h23' or 'h24'. See:
    // developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/Locale
    // Intl.Locale.prototype.hourCycles
    // Returns an Array of hour cycle identifiers, indicating either
    // the 12-hour format ("h11", "h12") or
    // the 24-hour format ("h23", "h24").

    // A 12-hour clock type value has the format '7 AM', '10 PM', or
    // '7 π.μ.' (if the locale language is Greek as specified
    // by the two letter ISO 639-1 code "el" or 
    // three letter ISO 639-2 code "ell").

    const hr = new Intl.DateTimeFormat(languages, { hour: "numeric" }).format();

    // If there's no space in the value of the 'hr' variable then
    // the value is a string representing a number between and
    // can include '0' and '24'. See comment above regarding "hourCycles".
    // Return 'true' if a space exists.
    //if (!hr.match(/\s/)) { return true; }
    // Or simply:
    // return !hr.match(/\s/);

    // Alternatively, check if the value of 'hr' is an integer.
    // E.g. Number.isInteger(Number('10 AM')) returns 'false'
    // E.g. Number.isInteger(Number('7 π.μ.')) returns 'false'
    // E.g. Number.isInteger(Number('10')) returns 'true'
    return Number.isInteger(Number(hr));
};
```

Usage:

```
const isBrowserLocaleClock24h = isBrowserLocaleClockType24h();
// or
const isBrowserLocaleClock24h = isBrowserLocaleClockType24h(navigator.language);
```

## Using Intl.Locale().hourCycles

Lastly, for much newer browser's (except Firefox as of Dec 2022), there's new Intl.Locale(navigator.language).hourCycles listed on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/Locale/hourCycles).

```
// developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some#checking_whether_a_value_exists_in_an_array
const hourCycles = new Intl.Locale(navigator.language).hourCycles;
const isBrowserLocale24h = ["h23", "h24"].some(hourCycle => hourCycles.includes(hourCycle));
```

[From](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/Locale/hourCycle)

> The Intl.Locale.prototype.hourCycle property is an accessor property that returns the time keeping format convention used by the locale.

> There are 2 main types of time keeping conventions (clocks) used around the world: the 12 hour clock and the 24 hour clock. The hourCycle property makes it easier for JavaScript programmers to access the clock type used by a particular locale.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
/*
 * Detects browser's locale 24h time preference
 * It works by checking whether hour output contains a space ('1 AM' or '01')
 */
const isBrowserLocale24h = () =>
  !new Intl.DateTimeFormat([], { hour: 'numeric' }).format(0).match(/\s/);
```

**EDIT:** Changed the first param from `undefined` to `[]` because the MDN docs say: `To use the browser's default locale, pass an empty array`.

Check browser compatibility of [Intl.DateTimeFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/DateTimeFormat#Browser_compatibility).

You can perhaps fallback to the following, but I'm not sure whether `AM/PM` designation (whichever characters are used) is at the end of the output for all locales. This just checks whether the last character is numeric:

```
Number.isFinite(Number((new Date()).toLocaleString().slice(-1)))
```

Answer (score 2):

Mario Bonaci's answer didn't work as expected for me though it pointed me to the right direction. Here's what I tried at first:

```js
/*
 * Detects navigator locale 24h time preference
 * It works by checking whether hour output contains AM ('1 AM' or '01 h')
 */
const isBrowserLocale24h = () =>
  !new Intl.DateTimeFormat(undefined, { hour: "numeric" })
    .format(0)
    .match(/AM/);
```

It didn't work as expected as it apparently takes the browser's install language and not the user preferred language. Changing the `undefined` to [`navigator.language`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorLanguage/language) did the trick. Here, we're checking the time format based on the user's preferred language:

```js
/*
 * Detects navigator locale 24h time preference
 * It works by checking whether hour output contains AM ('1 AM' or '01 h')
 * based on the user's preferred language
 */
const isBrowserLocale24h = () =>
  !new Intl.DateTimeFormat(navigator.language, { hour: "numeric" })
    .format(0)
    .match(/AM/);
```

Comment: I'm glad that helped. Did you try specifying `[]` instead of `undefined`, as the MDN docs say? I changed my answer to reflect that. Thanks for the feedback!